# Transfer LeapMotion coordinates into Unity coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates, leap-motion

I am working with Unity and a LeapMotionController. For my project i want to display an object on my palm.

I thought it would work in the way like this (see the code section). But the coordinates are very different...

In LeapMotion V2 there was a way in the SDK to transform this coordintates. But in 4.4 there is nothing like this anymore

- tried to scale these coordinates in such a way but it isn't the result that i want

```
...

void Update()
{
    Frame frame = controller.Frame ();
    for (int h = 0; h < frame.Hands.Count; h++) {
       Hand leapHand = frame.Hands [h];
       Vector3 handPostition = new Vector3(leapHand.PalmPosition.x, leapHand.PalmPosition.y, leapHand.PalmPosition.z)  
    }
}

...
```

I need the exact coordinates from the palm to display a 3D object relativ to the palm.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get the palm position is by using the ToVector3() function on leapHand.

```
Vector3 handPostition = leapHand.PalmPosition.ToVector3();
```

If you're looking for rotation as well then call

```
Quaternion handRotation = leapHand.Rotation.ToQuaternion();
```

And if you're looking for a way to get all of that in one hit then call

```
Leap.Unity.Pose pose = leapHand.GetPalmPose();
Vector3 handPosition = pose.position;
Quaternion handRotation = pose.rotation;
```